# How is this not an inner product space with the following inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the inner product defined as $\langle x,y \rangle = \frac{1}{4}(||x+y||^{2} - ||x-y||^{2})$, where $||x|| = |x_{1}|+|x_{2}|.$ I've been told that it isn't definite, but I can't see it. $\langle x,x \rangle = |x_{1}|^{2} + 2|x_{1}||x_{2}|+|x_{2}|^{2}=0$ implies $x=0$, no?

Comment: why is it bilinear?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Let me check. I took the "not definite" argument and focused on that.

Comment: What happens if you set $y=(0,0)$?

Comment: @GregMartin We get $\langle x,0 \rangle = 0$... but so what? That doesn't mean it's not definite.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Rather long computation, but it's definitely not sesquilinear.

Comment: @Mista indeed. And the failure of the parallelogram law, as pointed out below is usually one of the fastest way to prove something is not an inner product, but I just wanted you to notice that bilinearity fails directly as well.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For your expression to be a scalar product, the corresponding norm needs to satisfy the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law):
$$||x+y||^2+ ||x-y||^2 = 2||x||^2 + 2||y||^2$$

Now choose for example $x=(1,1)^T$ and $y= (-1,1)^T$ to see that the parallelogram law isn't satisfied.